# Como obtengo el id de un texbox cuando éste pierde el focus?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Estoy realizando una validación a muchos campos de texto, estos son dinámicos. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo saber el nombre de mi caja de texto con el metodo `onblur`? O sea, cuando se pierde el *focus*, quisiera saber el `id` de ese `textbox`. Este es mi código:

```
<script>
       function Validar(nota) {
           var idTexto = document.activeElement.id;
           var num = document.getElementById(idTexto).value;
           if (num == "") {
               alert("Introduzca nota");
               document.getElementById(idTexto).focus;
           } else
               return nota.value;
       }
</script>
```

Con este código obtengo el `id` del `texbox` donde esta el *focus*, pero no quiero eso. Necesito obtener el `id` del `texbox` donde se perdió el *focus*.

Comment: Podrías compartirnos la parte del `Html` que afecta este código `JavaScript`?

Comment: ¿qué es exactamente `nota`? Lo pasas como parámetro pero luego apenas se usa. ¿Y por qué la etiqueta de asp.net? Esto parece un problema de html y JS.

Comment: Seguro que quieres hacerlo en javascript puro? bien podrías usar un framework para que sea mas fácil.

Comment: No necesitas el ID, necesitas el objeto DOM. Para eso utilizas el dichoso `document.getElementById(...)`, en cambio existe en el entorno de la ejecución de un evento (`OnBlur` en este caso) los objetos "this" y "event" que pueden usarse como parametro de la llamada a la función que ejecuta. Es decir, algo como `OnBlur='Validar(this)';` es suficiente como para que la ahora variable "nota" (dentro de la función) sea el objeto DOM del textbox (o quien sea que hace esa llamada), por lo cual, dentro de la función puedes utilizar `var num = nota.value;` y `nota.focus;` (sin necesitar `var idtexto`).

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar un parámetro más a tu función Validar:

```
function Validar(nota, id)
{
    ...
}
```

En la llamada a la función javascript puedes colocar:

```
onBlur="Validar(tu_valor, this.id)"
```